# Switch from one screen to another on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to switch from one screen to another - from a category screen to a detail screen - in my BlackBerry app.  I don't know how to switch from one screen to another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are in the event thread (the default thread your program runs on if it's a UI application and you haven't started any other threads), then opening up another screen can be done by calling the **pushScreen()** method of the **UiApplication** class.

Since, in a typical case, your application derives from **UiApplication**, you would take a reference to your application object and call **pushScreen()** on it with the parameter of your new screen:

```
myApp.pushScreen(new MyNewScreen());
```

If you're running in a worker thread, or in any context where you either don't have access to a UiApplication or pushing a screen would not be allowed (you're only allowed to work with UI components on the original UI thread), then pushing a screen onto the screen stack is a bit different -- you need to switch to the UI thread, and then push the new screen onto the screen stack:

```
Application.getApplication().invokeLater(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Ui.getUiEngine().pushScreen(new MyNewScreen());
        }
    }
);
```

At Antair, we have a simple **ScreenChanger** class that’s part of a larger internal library that we use for all of our projects. Here’s a stripped-down version of the **ScreenChanger** class for you to use.

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Antair Library for BlackBerry Devices
// ScreenChanger.java
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


package com.antair.blackberrylib.ui;


import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui;


interface ScreenChangerListener
{
    void onScreenChangeComplete(Screen openedScreen, Screen closedScreen);
}


final class ScreenChanger
{
    static void change ( Screen screenToOpen, ScreenChangerListener listener )
    {
        ScreenChanger.change(screenToOpen, null, listener);
    }


    static void change ( Screen screenToOpen, Screen screenToClose,
        ScreenChangerListener listener )
    {
        Application.getApplication().invokeLater(
            new EventThreadScreenChanger(screenToOpen, screenToClose, listener));
    }


    static void close ( Screen screenToClose, ScreenChangerListener listener )
    {
        Application.getApplication().invokeLater(
            new EventThreadScreenChanger(null, screenToClose, listener));
    }
}


final class EventThreadScreenChanger extends Thread
{
    Screen _screenToOpen;
    Screen _screenToClose;
    ScreenChangerListener _listener;


    EventThreadScreenChanger ( Screen screenToOpen, Screen screenToClose,
        ScreenChangerListener listener )
    {
        _screenToOpen = screenToOpen;
        _screenToClose = screenToClose;
        _listener = listener;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        if ( _screenToOpen != null )
        {
            try
            {
                Ui.getUiEngine().pushScreen(_screenToOpen);
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                // Your error handler
            }
        }

        if ( _screenToClose != null )
        {
            try
            {
                Ui.getUiEngine().popScreen(_screenToClose);
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                // Your error handler
            }
        }

        if ( _listener != null )
        {
            _listener.onScreenChangeComplete(_screenToOpen, _screenToClose);
        }
    }
}
```